# Datasets not joining

Tags: r, join

I'm having trouble joining FBI crime data with school districts.

There are some cities/towns that have the same name in the same state, so county is given as a way to separate these values. For the years 2003-2017 there are roughly 1700 values that also have counties. However, when I try to join this dataset with another school district dataset, limited values join (if I inner join, I'll get 200 out of the 1700). On this forum, with another question ([Issues with Character Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715121/issues-with-character-values/57727781#57727781)), other members helped me solve an issue with whitespace, but oddly, this didn't help the joining of the datasets. Below is a dput for Adams county in Pennsylvania for both the crime data and the school districts.

A simple left_join should work, but you'll see that I don't get any of the district values. Inner_join yields zero rows, so there's some issue in the data where something isn't being recognized. STATE, COUNTY, and CITY are all character, year is numeric. These are the variables by which the two columns are joined.

I tried trimming white space around all categorical variables. No dice.

As a rule of thumb, I join by district_ids, place_ids, etc., but the FBI crime data is clunky, and doesn't have any of that, so categorical it is.

crime data

```
structure(list(CITY = c("conewago", "conewago", "cumberland", 
"conewago", "cumberland", "liberty", "conewago", "liberty", "conewago", 
"cumberland", "liberty", "conewago", "cumberland", "liberty", 
"conewago", "cumberland", "liberty", "conewago", "cumberland", 
"conewago", "cumberland", "conewago", "cumberland", "conewago", 
"cumberland", "conewago", "cumberland", "liberty", "conewago", 
"cumberland"), COUNTY = c("adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county"), STATE = c("pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania"), year = c(2006, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2003, 2003)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

district data

```
structure(list(CITY = c("east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", 
"bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", 
"fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "east berlin", "york springs", 
"abbottstown", "bonneauville", "mcsherrystown", "new oxford", 
"carroll valley", "fairfield", "gettysburg", "bonneauville", 
"littlestown", "arendtsville", "bendersville", "biglerville", 
"east berlin", "york springs", "abbottstown", "bonneauville", 
"mcsherrystown", "new oxford", "carroll valley", "fairfield", 
"gettysburg", "bonneauville", "littlestown", "arendtsville", 
"bendersville", "biglerville", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", 
"midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", 
"mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", 
"gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", 
"lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", 
"lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", 
"aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", 
"hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", 
"hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", 
"lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", 
"table rock", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", 
"orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", 
"orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", 
"heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", 
"midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", 
"mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", 
"gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", 
"lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", 
"lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", 
"aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", 
"hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", 
"hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", 
"lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", 
"table rock", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", 
"orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", 
"orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", 
"heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", 
"midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", 
"mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", 
"gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", 
"lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", 
"lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", 
"aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", 
"hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", 
"hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", 
"lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", 
"table rock", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", 
"orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", 
"orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", 
"heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", 
"midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", "lake heritage", 
"mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", 
"gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", "hampton", "idaville", 
"lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", "hunterstown", 
"lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", "lake heritage", 
"aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", "table rock", 
"hampton", "idaville", "lake meade", "midway", "orrtanna", "cashtown", 
"hunterstown", "lake heritage", "mcknightstown", "orrtanna", 
"lake heritage", "aspers", "flora dale", "gardners", "heidlersburg", 
"table rock"), COUNTY = c("adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county", "adams county", 
"adams county", "adams county", "adams county"), STATE = c("pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", "pennsylvania", 
"pennsylvania"), year = c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -450L))
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a minimal reproducible example--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Please use text, not images/links, for text. Quote/paraphrase necessary text from elsewhere & say how it relates to your problem. Make your post self-contained. PS That is not "minimal" representative input.

Answer (score 1):

Note

```
> intersect(crime$CITY, district$CITY)
character(0)
```

while

```
> intersect(crime$COUNTY, district$COUNTY)
[1] "adams county"
```

Some of your columns (like CITY) don't overlap at all so you can't merge (join) them on those vectors.

Comment: It took me a couple reads to parse your `all()` statement. I'd suggest simplifying to, say, `intersect(crime$CITY, district$CITY)`, which will return an empty vector indicating there are no cities in common. Same result, but seems clearer to me. Or even `any(crime$CITY %in% district$CITY)`, which still seems cleaner.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice. There's something weird going on with different IDs that I need to figure out, where certain values aren't being included, which is why the cities don't overlap in that dput. So many moving parts...ugh.

Comment: If that was helpful, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark on the left.